# business phone regex containing if-else expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write business phone number regex in javascript, my requirements are:

- It should contain only digits,dashes and whitespaces
- It should not end with `-` but can end with whitespaces
- There should be only 1 `-` between two groups
- It should match numbers with and without `-` like `1`, `123`, `678-78`

I have tried following regex but it fails for `123--` as it is invalid one anybody please                       suggest me something

```
/^([ ]*[0-9]+[-]?[0-9 ]*?([-])[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*|[0-9 ]*[ ]*)+$/.test('123--2')
```

Comment: It should not end with "`- `" either, right?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 yes it should not end with -

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Can you tell me have I done anything wrong in  ?(exp) yes|no part?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/^[0-9]+(-[0-9\s]+)*$/
```

Comment: @Pumbaa80 it returns false for ' 1 ' ,my requirement is it should be true

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need an answer to this, but this works for your requirements:

```
/^(?!.+-\s*$)\s*((?:\d+\s*-?\s*)+)$/
```

Explanation:

- `^` start of string
- `(?!.+-\s*$)` disallow `-` (or `-` followed by whitespace) at the end of the string
- `\s*` optional leading spaces
- `(` start capturing
- `(?:\d+\s*-?\s*)+` one or more groups of the following:

  - one or more digits,
  - possibly followed by whitespace,
  - possibly followed by a single hyphen,
  - possibly followed by more whitespace
- `)` stop capturing
- `$` end of the string

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/iS6wA3/2)